# How to compare duplicate files in the same directory and hardlink them together

Tags: linux, bash, rhel, scripting, shell-script

i have variable that i used to represent duplicated files found in a certain directory

```
ddub=`find $1* -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -rn | uniq -d | xargs -I{} find -type f -size {}c -print0 `
```

I then looped over this directory to compare hard link any duplicates to the original file as well

```
echo $ddub                              #Print the results

for i in $ddub; do
    for j in $ddub ; do
    if cmp -s "$i" "j" ; then
         ln $i $j
    elif ; 
         echo "csnt hardlink the files"
    fi
```

The problem here is that it tries to hard link every single file in the list which doesn't work as i would like to. I would like to separate the unique files from the rest and then hard link them.

How do i further loop over this so as to hardlink only similar MD5sum files found in the list or files with the same size?

the results i get are as follows which is just the list of all the files i created. please help me figure out how i can seperate them further (note i just created random files)

```
ln ./test_dir/test_dir2/29.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/29.JPG.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/29.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/29.JPG./test_dir/29.JPG.copy./test_dir/29.JPG.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/23.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/23.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/09.JPG.copy./test_dir/09.JPG./test_dir/09.JPG.copy.copy./test_dir/39.JPG./test_dir/39.JPG.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/22.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/22.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/22.JPG.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/22.JPG./test_dir/22.JPG.copy.copy./test_dir/22.JPG.copy ./test_dir/test_dir2/29.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/29.JPG.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/29.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/29.JPG./test_dir/29.JPG.copy./test_dir/29.JPG.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/23.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/23.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/09.JPG.copy./test_dir/09.JPG./test_dir/09.JPG.copy.copy./test_dir/39.JPG./test_dir/39.JPG.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/22.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/22.JPG.copy.copy.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/test_dir2/22.JPG.copy.copy.copy./test_dir/22.JPG./test_dir/22.JPG.copy.copy./test_dir/22.JPG.copy
[asonganyif@ccad2 November_2016]$ vim bashScripass.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare files with `[ a = b ]`. Use `cmp`:

```
if cmp -s "$i" "$j"; then
# rest as you were
```

Comment: Thank, so is this going to compare similar files amongst the list in the given directory ? and if the output is zero can it just create the hard links then? and possibly delete the rest of the files? Ill like for it to do something like this ...for i in `find $ddub -type f`; do
    for j in `find $ddub -type f`; do
        if cmp -s "$i" "$j" ; then
            echo `ln $i $j`
        elif ;
            echo "files are not dupicates"
        fi
    done
done
i appreciate this help !

Comment: else, not elif, but possibly should work.  Pretty inefficient, looping over both; compares A with B and then B with A, but I'll leave it to you to improve that :)